# Warning while Running report: Found two components for namespace

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have problem with report using *JasperReports*. I ran report on my program, it works, but there were error message just like this

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment findComponentBundles
```

`WARNING: Found two components for namespace http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components`

When I searched any recommendation as same as mine, none is solution. Do you know how to fix this?

This' jrxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="imp1_bln" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="thn_proses" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="bln_proses" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT DISTINCT
     m_negara."id_negara" AS ID_Negara,
     m_negara."nama_negara" AS Nama_Negara,
     import_det."netto_hs" AS Curr_Net,
     SUM(import_det.netto_hs)AS Cumm_Net,
     import_det."cif_hs_us" AS Curr_CIF,
     SUM(import_det.cif_hs_us)AS Cumm_CIF,
     batch_hdr."bln_proses" AS batch_hdr_bln_proses,
     batch_hdr."thn_proses" AS batch_hdr_thn_proses
FROM
     m_hs10digit, m_negara, import_det, batch_hdr, import

 WHERE

    "dbo".import.negara_pemasok=dbo.m_negara.id_negara AND dbo.import_det.sk_import=dbo.import.sk_import
    AND dbo.import.sk_batch=dbo.batch_hdr.sk_batch
    AND dbo.batch_hdr.bln_proses between 01 and $P{bln_proses}

GROUP BY
    m_negara."id_negara",
    m_negara."nama_negara",
    import_det."netto_hs",
    import_det."cif_hs_us",
    batch_hdr."bln_proses",
    batch_hdr."thn_proses"]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID_Negara" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Nama_Negara" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Curr_Net" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="Cumm_Net" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="Curr_CIF" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="Cumm_CIF" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="93" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="1" y="2" width="146" height="91"/>
                <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["coffee.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="146" y="58" width="410" height="35"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isItalic="false" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Tabel Impor Menurut Negara Asal (Import By Country of Origin)]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="41" height="19"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Bulan :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="64" y="0" width="39" height="19"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Tahun:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="56" height="39"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Kode Negara]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="146" y="59" width="90" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Bulan Ini]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="235" y="59" width="129" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Kumulatif]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="55" y="40" width="92" height="39"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Negara Asal]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="363" y="59" width="50" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Bulan Ini]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="412" y="59" width="144" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Kumulatif]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="146" y="40" width="218" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Berat Bersih (Netto)]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="363" y="40" width="193" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[CIF (US $)]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="102" y="0" width="35" height="19"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{thn_proses}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="40" y="0" width="25" height="19"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$P{bln_proses}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="32" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="1" y="-1" width="55" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{ID_Negara}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="146" y="-1" width="90" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double"><![CDATA[$F{Curr_Net}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="235" y="-1" width="129" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double"><![CDATA[$F{Cumm_Net}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="55" y="-1" width="92" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{Nama_Negara}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="363" y="0" width="50" height="19"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double"><![CDATA[$F{Curr_CIF}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="412" y="-1" width="144" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double"><![CDATA[$F{Cumm_CIF}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Can you post the *jrxml* file?

Comment: The [ComponentsEnvironment](http://code.jaspersoft.com/svn/repos/jasperreports/trunk/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/component/ComponentsEnvironment.java) class writes this warning. May be there are several *JasperReports* libraries in your classpath

Comment: Sorry, actually the JasperReports library has been added in my application, so what do you mean about "May be there are several JasperReports libraries in your classpath"?

Comment: you might be having multiple jar with different version for Jasper in your buildpath, That cause the issue.

Answer (score 7):

It means that you have several *jar* files in your JasperReports Library classpath... just use:

- commons-beanutils-1.8.0
- commons-collections-2.1.1
- commons-digester-1.7
- commons-javaflow-20060411
- commons-logging-1.0.4
- groovy-all-1.7.5
- iText-2.1.7
- jasperreports-4.5.0 (any version)
- png-encoder-1.5
- poi-3.7-20101029 (Or poi-3.6)

and problem solved...

Answer (score 2):

The jasperreports-maven-plugin repeats the jasperreports dependency. I had your problem when  I changed the version of my jasperreports dependency but did not also change it in the dependency of the jasperreports-maven-plugin.

Comment: In addition to specifying the same dependency version of jasperreports for both the code and the plugin, I had to add the scope `runtime` to the module dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Just delete jasperreports-javaflow*.jar from your classpath during report compilation.
The error should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I updated primefaces jar file from 3.5 to 4.0. It is solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest downloadable jasper jar zip(Japsperreports-6.3.0.jar) it does not provide all the needed jar files.You have to find the jar files.
For eliminate issues just add

jasperreports-6.3.0.jar , 
org.apache.commons.collections.jar , 
commons-logging-1.2.jar , 
commons-digester-2.1.jar , 
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar ,

will work fine..