# Send List to a sub report and call it in the main report

Tags: java, list, jasper-reports

I have a method that generates a pdf report sending a List as a data source and saves in a given directory, now it became necessary to use a sub report, but am having trouble understanding how I can pass a List as a data source for this sub report and then display it in the main report.

This is my method that generates the main report:

```
 public boolean generateReport(List list, int numeroRelatorio, String nomePrestador, String dataSistema) {
        JasperReport report = null;
        InputStream image = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/br/com/xml/relatorio/LOGO.png");
        filtro.put("Image", image);
        try {
            InputStream inputStreamReal = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/br/com/xml/relatorio/MainReport.jrxml");
            report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStreamReal);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(frmPegaXml.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao pegar arquivos!", "ERRO!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        try {
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, filtro, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print,
                    "C:/Demonstrativos/" + dataSistema + "/" + nomePrestador + "_" + dataSistema + "_" + numeroRelatorio + ".pdf");
            return true;

        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(frmPegaXml.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao Gerar relatório, verifique se nenhum arquivo está aberto ou se o nome está correto!\n" + ex, "ERRO!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return false;
        }

    }
```

---

I tried that way but it didn't work:

```
filtro.put("listaDados", list);
filtro.put("localizarRel", "src/br/com/xml/relatorio/subRelatorio.jasper");
```

That was the exception:

```
15/05/21 10:36:25 ERROR fill.JRFillSubreport: Fill 1: exception
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : dataRealizacao
```

This Bean dataRealizacao is part of my sub report, does anyone know where I might be missing?

---

Update Question:
Class Procedimentos:

```
public class Procedimentos {

    private String numLote;
    private String dataRealizacao;
    private String descriçãoServico;
    private String codTab;
    private String codigoServico;
    private String quantidadeExecutada;
    private BigDecimal valorProcessado;
    private BigDecimal valorLiberado;
    private BigDecimal valorGlosa;
    private String codigoGlosa;
    private String sequenciaGuiaProcedimento;
    private String sequenciaGuiaDados;
    private String nomeBeneficiario;
    private String valorLiberadoGuia;
    ...
```

My SubReport:
[image]

I have 2 parameters in my main report:
`listaDados (java.util.List)` and `localizarRel (java.lang.String)` with expression default = "`C: \ Users \ Adiego \ JaspersoftWorkspace \ MyReports \ subRelatorio.jasper"`

And in my main report on the subreport properties I do it:
[image]

Comment: Where you define the bean dataRealizacao ?

Comment: In my class "Procedimentos" . I'll edit the question to better understanding

Comment: I edited the question, see if you can help me.

Comment: try to put blank if null on the fields ...the error message looks related to dataRealizacao....

Comment: Ready, I put "Blank When null" and I changed the List that was wrong. Now there's no error, but the application is stopped in this part.

`05/15/21 11:54:39 WARN component.ComponentsEnvironment: Found two components for namespace http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670456/warning-while-running-report-found-two-components-for-namespace

Comment: I did it and the error disappeared, but the application continues to be paused

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YmcUA.png

Comment: Is stopped in this part